# Atom Editor - status bar is missing

Tags: atom-editor

How is this bar called? Status bar?

[image]

My friend can not see it in his editor, how can he get it back?

[image]

Comment: In the editor preferences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This bar is provided by the [status-bar](https://atom.io/packages/status-bar) package.

Like many Atom packages, it has a settings panel.

- Settings
- Packages
- search for "status bar"
- click "Settings" on "status-bar" package

There you will fine a checkbox, "Is Visible". It is probably unchecked.

Another possibility is that this package has been disabled. Just click "Enable" in that case to turn it back on.

[image]

Comment: I just upgraded atom and it disabled the Status Bar... it was pretty frustrating since I didn't realize it was disabled, just gone. Your answer made me think to double check that! Thanks!

Comment: What or where would I edit so that it did not display the msg in the lower right corner "File not yet committed"

I'd prefer to not have any version control at all.

Thank you